# Radio button don't work with UiBootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need this time a help with this example:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/AU4AsLiUpANTRBQHO5as?p=preview)

You can see that the css on example **1** goes good. When you click on the button the state of the button change (press)

On example **2** i can't do the same. **on my app i need that the "radio button" appear on vertical line (*i get it*)**.

But when i press the button, when i click out i back to the first state (don't press)

```
<h4>Exmaple 2</h4>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="company in vm_login.decimals">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel.id" btn-radio="company.id">
            {{company.desc}}
        </button>

    </div>
</div>
```

***Can anybody help me?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a final version and this is how i need

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/VLK98Kce7JXy5Zvl1rhK?p=preview)**

Thanks for all

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" >
    <button ng-repeat="value in vm_login.options"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            type="button"
            ng-model="vm_login.model"
            btn-radio="value.id">
        {{value.desc}}
    </button>
</div>
<p>texto aqui: {{vm_login.model}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `btn-group` classed element expects it's children to be buttons (a `btn` classed element). Not a `div` element. Take out the `div` and move the `ng-repeat` to the actual button. Now if you want your button to align verticaly you'll need to use `btn-group-vertical` instead of `btn-group` as stated in the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-vertical). Here's the update code:

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button ng-repeat="company in vm_login.decimals" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel.id" btn-radio="company.id">
        {{company.desc}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kVFqNAXisMgkMVqy0WAF?p=preview

Comment: but i need that it look in vertical, is for that reason that i put into a div, can you tell me how to see all the button in vertical ?

Comment: also on your example, i can see that when you click over the button, it work, the state change (press), but when you click out, the last button pressed must continue preseed.... but in your example it doesn't occur

Comment: Perfect ... iH8

The other thinks is that i talk in my last comment: "when you click out (any other part of the view) the last button click must continue pressed, But it doesn't occur)

On your example

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me try this approach in one line without using buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-primary"  ng-repeat="company in vm_login.decimals" ng-model="radioModel"  ng-model="radioModel.id" btn-radio="company.id">{{company.desc}}</label>
    </div>
```